# ElasticSearch: Running two clusters locally with esvm

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to run two clusters with `esvm` tool. However, I keep getting this error:

**esvm --list 2m3d 2m3d-v2**

```
> /usr/lib/node_modules/esvm/node_modules/rcfinder/index.js:138
>       if (sync && err) throw err;
>                        ^
> 
> SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 780
>     at Object.parse (native)
>     at RcFinder.loader (/usr/lib/node_modules/esvm/node_modules/rcfinder/index.js:20:17)
>     at get (/usr/lib/node_modules/esvm/node_modules/rcfinder/index.js:68:18)
>     at respond (/usr/lib/node_modules/esvm/node_modules/rcfinder/index.js:112:37)
>     at RcFinder.find (/usr/lib/node_modules/esvm/node_modules/rcfinder/index.js:158:14)
>     at RcLoader.for (/usr/lib/node_modules/esvm/node_modules/rcloader/index.js:76:43)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/esvm/bin/esvm.js:19:26)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>     at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
>     at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
>     at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

for the `.esvmrc` with the following content:

```
{
  "clusters": {
    "2m3d": {
      "plugins": ["mobz/elasticsearch-head"],
      "nodes": [
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "master-1", "data": false, "master": true }
        },
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "master-2", "data": false, "master": true }
        },
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "data-1", "data": true, "master": false }
        },
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "data-2", "data": true, "master": false }
        },
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "data-3", "data": true, "master": false }
        }
      ]
    }
        "2m3d-v2": {
          "plugins": ["mobz/elasticsearch-head"],
          "nodes": [
            {
              "cluster": { "name": "2m3d-v2" },
              "node": { "name": "master-1", "data": false, "master": true }
            },
            {
              "cluster": { "name": "2m3d-v2" },
              "node": { "name": "master-2", "data": false, "master": true }
            },
            {
              "cluster": { "name": "2m3d-v2" },
              "node": { "name": "data-1", "data": true, "master": false }
            },
            {
              "cluster": { "name": "2m3d-v2" },
              "node": { "name": "data-2", "data": true, "master": false }
            },
            {
              "cluster": { "name": "2m3d-v2" },
              "node": { "name": "data-3", "data": true, "master": false }
            }
          ]
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a comma before `"2m3d-v2"` in your config file

Comment: Naturally you were right! However the `esvm --list 2m3d 2m3d-v2` is not really starting the both clusters. How one can start this config file to run two such clusters? Do I have to run two separate processes with `esvm 2m3d` and `esvm 2m3d-v2` or can it be done with one esvm command?

Comment: I think you can only start one cluster at the same time. However, you can run esvm from two different terminals.

Comment: Yup, just did. However with the `elasticsearch-head` plugin I keep getting only one of the clusters while [here](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/5f01aae07364c95b6c8ddfe39423d6d19932158d/687474703a2f2f6d6f627a2e6769746875622e636f6d2f656c61737469637365617263682d686561642f73637265656e73686f74732f636c75737465724f766572766965772e706e67) I can see 2 additional columns (bnvil cu_msg) which I thought were for 2 separate clusters.

Comment: You need to check the ports used in your second cluster and use that to connect to the head plugin of the second cluster

Comment: Ok, but what are the `bnvil` and the `cu_msg` columns then in that graphic ?